# Scroolbar can not set on right side on this App

Tags: python, tkinter

**Scrollbar not working my code is**

```
 from tkinter import*
 from tkinter import ttk
    class Sill_App:
     def __init__(self,root):
      self.root = root
     self.root.geometry("1300x700+0+0")
     self.root.title("Billing Software")
     bg_color = "#074463"
     title = Label(self.root,text = "JIBAN PRABHA 
     PATHOLAB",bd=12,relief=GROOVE,bg=bg_color,fg="white",
     font = ("ALGERIAN",20),pady=2).pack(fill=X)
     # Patient's Test Report Details Frame
     F3 = LabelFrame(self.root,text="Patient's Test Report Details",font= 
     ("Calibri(body)",15,"bold"),fg="black",bd=7)
     F3.place(width=490,height=500,x=774,y=57)
     AddData_lbl = Label(F3,text="Patient's Test Report",bd=5,fg="black",font=("Bell 
     MT",12,"bold")).pack()
     self.text_area = Text(F3,bg="gray",fg="white",width=42,height=18,font=("Bell 
     MT",15,"bold"))
     self.text_area.pack()
     # self.text_area.place(x=776,y=58)
     scroll_y = ttk.Scrollbar(self.text_area,orient=VERTICAL)
     scroll_y.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
     self.text_area.config(yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)
     scroll_y.config(command=self.text_area.yview)
    
           
if __name__=="__main__":   
  root =Tk()
  obj = Sill_App(root)
  root.mainloop()
```

**please help me**

Comment: Try changing `self.text_area.pack()` to `self.text_area.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)`. Also it is better to change the parent of the scrollbar to `F3`.

Comment: working fine thnk u